# Make spaces consistent

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a query which will make spaces between the string consistent

***i.e.*** Field order_text contains strings they may be separated by single space or double or triple we are not sure about how many spaces are there. What I need to do is make these spaces consistent (i.e. 2 spaces)

```
mysql> SELECT order_text  FROM customer_cp_abdul LIMIT 4;
+------------------------------------------+
| order_text                               |
+------------------------------------------+
| Mar-2009-1008                            |
| Mar-2009-514  Sep-2009-1603  Mar-2010-22 |
| Mar-2009-2505  May-2009-2733             |
| Mar-2009-1160                            |
+------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: In the general case, this is a beast of a problem.  Who came up with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a trick you can use for this:

```
select replace(replace(replace(order_text, ' ', '<>'), '><', ''), '<>', ' ')
from customer_cp_abdul
limit 4;
```

It replaces spaces with "<>".  Multiple spaces end up looking like `'<><><>'`.  Then, the `><` are removed, so you get `'<>'`.  And then one more replace.  Voila!  A single space.

Comment: There could be lot many values in strings i.e. Mar-2009-514  Sep-2009-1603  Mar-2010-22 Mar-2009-514  Sep-2009-1603  Mar-2010-22 Mar-2009-514  Sep-2009-1603  Mar-2010-22 Mar-2009-514  Sep-2009-1603  Mar-2010-22 , this will work for it as well ?

Comment: It should work for any number of spaces. You can run this query and test it: select replace(replace(replace('Mar-2009-514    Sep-2009-1603  Mar-2010-22      Sep-2012-463', ' ', '<>'), '><', ''), '<>', '  ')

Comment: this is pure magic Voila !!! This answer should be in Hall of Fame on SO.